# Опечатка в плашке, которую оставляет Дух Сообщества, поднимая пост на главную

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Непорядок. :)

[image: freehand circles ftw]

Comment: Угу. Правильно так: "содержитъ", это же для солидныхъгосподъ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь!

Опечатка была исправлена:

> Этот вопрос **содержит** ответы, которые могут быть как хорошими, так и плохими; система предложила их на проверку.

Изменения вступят в силу по синхронизации переводов.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80339/discussion-on-answer-by-aer-------).

Comment: Ну и где эта [синхронизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595463)?

Comment: @alexolut как связана ссылка с вашим комментарием? Уверен, вы сами понимаете, как работает та самая синхронизация.

Comment: Там была плашка Духа до того, как ответ добавили. Посмотрите любой другой вопрос, поднятый Духом, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597657/176217). Я понимаю, как оно работает, поэтому каждый раз пинал КМ, чтобы переводы действительно подхватились как можно оперативнее.

Comment: @alexolut спасибо за интересную информацию. Мне нравятся менее травматичные способы общения с КМ. Более того, почему же *вы* не можете попросить обновить строки и пишете мне?

Comment: @Aer, Не вполне понятно почему это должен делать alexolut, если переводили(исправляли) Вы.

Comment: @vp_arth над переводом работает команда переводчиков, и добавляю переводы не только я.